# raw_id_fields with pages field does not work

Tags: django, django-cms

There are several issues if we add "pages" field to `raw_id_fields`.

1. When I click on search button, pages dialog opens, and if I select any page, nothing happens (I think that context variable `is_popup` from `render_page_row` method in `cms/utils/admin.py` should additionally check if `IS_POPUP_VAR` is present in `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']`)
2. If problem 1. is fixed, click on page adds page id but also all parent ids all the way to the tree root (I think that propagation of onclick event should be stopped)
3. It is not possible to open child nodes without selecting parent. When parent node arrow is clicked in order to see and add child node, parent is selected and dialog is closed. Result of adding onclick event handler on cms-tree-node.

Is it possible to add onclick event only for page link and not on the whole element with class cms-tree-node, so we can open node children without selecting page?

### Environment

Python version: 2.7
Django version: 1.8
django CMS version: 3.4.4

Comment: Have you got any errors in the console for failed javascript or anything like that if the default CMS behaviour isn't working?

Comment: No, didn't get any console errors